# Solving 2 unknown using vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

ABCDEF is a regular hexagon and O is the centre of the regular hexagon .

Vector OB = $b$ , Vector OC = $c$ . The side FA is produced to a point G such that FA : AG = 1 : 2.

The line DG meets OC at point X such that

vector DX = $h$ DG , where h is a constant . 
Express vector DX in terms of $h$, $b$, $c$,

Given also that vector OX = $k$ OC , where k is a constant , express vector OX in terms of $k$ and $c$,

hence find the value of $h$ and of $k$

I found :
Vector DX = $2h ( -c + 2b ) $

Vector OX = $ kc$

Now I have 2 unknowns , I'm not sure on how to start to find unknowns $k$ and $h$, I thought of simultaneous equations but I don't know how to start. Can I get a hint ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You are missing out a lot of information in your question! What is $OF, OA$? We don't need your $b$ yet and in your picture we have a redundant $E$.

Comment: @ctst The hexagon is a lattice generated by b and c.

Comment: Isn't it weird that $b$ and $c$ isn't drawn as having the same length as the sides in the triangle? Isn't it meant to?

Comment: @Lovsovs: I dare guess the picture is intentionally drawn a bit incorrectly. If it were completely accurate, it would point at a solution in an unintended way (insert evil grin emoticon). Me thinks the ratio FA:AG=1:2 is a very special case, but whoever assigned the problem wants students to use a method that would work for other ratios as well.

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*:
$$\vec{OD}=\vec{BC}=c-b$$
Now write $\vec{OX}$ as $\vec{OD}+\vec{DX}$, and then in terms of $b$ and $c$. For $\vec{OX}$ to be a multiple of $c$, the multiple of $b$ in its expression must be zero – what $h$ will achieve this? Once you've found it, substitute to find $k$.